# Observable vs Future Performance

Tags: performance, scala, asynchronous, future, rx-scala

I am working with Vert.x 2.x (http://vertx.io) which makes extensive use of asynchronous callbacks.  These quickly become unwieldy with typical nesting/callback hell issues.

I have considered both Scala Futures/Promises (which I think would be the defacto approach) and also Reactive Extensions (RxScala).

From my testing I have found some interesting performance results.

My testing is pretty basic, I'm just issuing a bunch of HTTP requests (via weighttp) to a Vert.x verticle that makes an asynchronous call across the Vert.x eventbus, and processes a response that is then returned in an HTTP 200 response.

What I have found is the following (performance here is measured in terms of HTTP requests per second):

- Async Callback performance = **68,305 rps**
- Rx performance = **64,656 rps**
- Future/Promises performance = **61,376 rps**

The test conditions were:

- Mac Pro OS X Yosemite 10.10.2
- Oracle JVM 1.8U25
- weighttp version 0.3
- Vert.x 2.1.5
- Scala 2.10.4
- RxScala 0.23.0
- 4 x Web Service Verticle Instances
- 4 x Backend Service Verticle Instances

The test command was

```
weighttp -n 1000000 -c 128 -7 8 -k "localhost:8888"
```

The figures above are the average of five test runs less best and worst result. Note the results are very consistent around the presented average (no more than a few hundred rps deviation).

Is there any known reason why the above might be happening - i.e. Rx > Futures in pure requests per second?

Reactive Extensions in my opinion are superior as they can do so much more but given the standard approach to async callbacks typically seems to go down the Futures/Promises track I'm surprised at the performance hit.

**EDIT:  Here is the Web Service Verticle**

```
class WebVerticle extends Verticle {
  override def start() {
    val port = container.env().getOrElse("HTTP_PORT", "8888").toInt
    val approach = container.env().getOrElse("APPROACH", "ASYNC")
    container.logger.info("Listening on port: " + port)
    container.logger.info("Using approach: " + approach)

    vertx.createHttpServer.requestHandler { req: HttpServerRequest =>
      approach match {
        case "ASYNC" => sendAsync(req, "hello")
        case "FUTURES" => sendWithFuture("hello").onSuccess { case body => req.response.end(body) }
        case "RX" => sendWithObservable("hello").doOnNext(req.response.end(_)).subscribe()
      }
    }.listen(port)
  }

  // Async callback
  def sendAsync(req: HttpServerRequest, body: String): Unit = {
    vertx.eventBus.send("service.verticle", body, { msg: Message[String] =>
      req.response.end(msg.body())
    })
  }

  // Rx 
  def sendWithObservable(body: String) : Observable[String] = {
    val subject = ReplaySubject[String]()
    vertx.eventBus.send("service.verticle", body, { msg: Message[String] =>
      subject.onNext(msg.body())
      subject.onCompleted()
    })
    subject
  }

  // Futures    
  def sendWithFuture(body: String) : Future[String] = {
    val promise = Promise[String]()
    vertx.eventBus.send("service.verticle", body, { msg: Message[String] =>
      promise.success(msg.body())
    })
    promise.future
  }
}
```

**EDIT:  Here is the Backend Verticle**

```
class ServiceVerticle extends Verticle {
  override def start(): Unit = {
    vertx.eventBus.registerHandler("service.verticle", { msg: Message[String] =>
      msg.reply("Hello Scala")
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing the actual benchmarks. Could you share them please?

Comment: When the response is received from the event bus, in the callback and rxscala cases, it's the same thread which is generating the http response; but with the promise there's one more inter-thread handoff before the http response. But, wouldn't expect 25% from this..

Comment: Really interesting post. Please share the benchmarks

Comment: @tariksbl - I have seen up to 25% performance difference, however this was with an asynchronous back end database call.

Comment: The difference looks more like 10%, no? At at that rps, object creation (with rx & future) and add'tl ctx switches (with future) could explain the perf difference.

Comment: @tariksbl - I have seen much greater differences in performance - but a more complex test case.  I'll be doing some more performance testing on my project soon and will post further details if I come across this again.